# Tabbed Navigation Style with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want a simple Tabbed Style Navigation that has a simple difference in the active state.  I have been having some difficulty achieving what I think should be a pretty easy task.

[image: Image of tabbed navigation]

In the Fiddle I show how I attempted it and though it could be done by adding 5px more of padding to `.current` and then a `margin-top: -5px`.  This does not achieve the look though.  I know this is probably something simple I am missing.

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<div class="page-wrap">
    <div class="main-nav">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="current">Latest Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.main-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.main-nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.main-nav li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
.main-nav ul {
  background-color: #333;
  line-height: 12px;
}
.main-nav a {
  padding: 15px 45px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #282b2e;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
}
.main-nav a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.main-nav .current {
  background: #ffffff;
}
.page-wrap {
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 500px;
}
```

**FIDDLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/j970s3mw/

Comment: here is a nice step by step instruction on how to build your own tabbed navigation. After reading this you will not only have your own nice navbar but also know what goes into making one so in future you can do it yourself without help  http://blixt.org/articles/tabbed-navigation-using-css#section=introduction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're facing this issue because you're using `overflow: hidden` on your `<ul>`. You will need to remove that and use `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left` to place your `<li>`'s next to each other.

Here's a **[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j970s3mw/12/)**.

```css
body {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.top {
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
}
.main-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.main-nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.main-nav li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.main-nav ul {
  background-color: #999;
  line-height: 12px;
}
.main-nav a {
  padding: 15px 45px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #282b2e;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
}
.main-nav a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.main-nav .current {
  background: #ffffff;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
.page-wrap {
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 500px;
}
a.current:hover {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="page-wrap">
        <div class="main-nav">
            <ul>
                <li> 
                <a href="#">Home</a></li><li> 
                <a href="#">Portfolio</a></li><li> 
                <a href="#">About</a></li><li> 
                <a href="#" class="current">Latest Projects</a></li><li> 
                <a href="#">Blog</a></li><li> 
                <a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Moreover, since you wouldn't want the hover styles set for the non-active tabs to affect the active tab, you can overwrite the styles for the current tab using:

```
a.current:hover {
      background: #fff;
      //add more styles as per your needs 
}
```

Comment: The top part dissapears on hover still.  How would you fix that?

Comment: Thank you, sir.  I've seen your answers here a lot.  You are very talented.  +1.  I've been learning quite a lot from you.

Comment: @godisgood The anchor tag with the `.current` class was inheriting the `:hover` state styles set for all of the anchor tags. I've defined separate styles for the hover state of anchor tag with `.current` class.

Comment: Now with your solution there is a weird space where the text cursor appears and is dead click space between the tabs.  Where did that come from?

Comment: @fogolicious Or forget that and check this: http://jsfiddle.net/j970s3mw/12/. If you look at the HTML, I've slightly modified the structure with respect to this article: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/. `display: inline-block` tends to add a `space` between to elements and it can be removed by restructuring the `<li>`'s.

Comment: Thank you for the help with this.  Your solution did end up working the way that I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/j970s3mw/5/)

Add this to your CSS:

```
.main-nav a:focus {
    background: #ffffff;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```

And jQuery, if you want the `.current` to be active at the beginning:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $('.current').removeClass('current');
});
```